# Problems changing from Enhanced for loop to normal for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

I am extracting data from a csv format to java. I have written some code for it.

```
Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(FilePath));
CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReaderBuilder(reader).build();
List<String[]> records = csvReader.readAll();

for(String[] record : records) {
    System.out.println(record[0]); // Note : Each record has two strings in it separated by delimiter ";"
    String[] parts = record[0].split(";"); //So I am splitting here
    System.out.println(parts[0]); //First part
    System.out.println(parts[1]); //Second part
}
```

My main aim is to store the parts after splitting each String from an array of Strings i.e., from "records". The console gives the output as how I expected. But I don't want to print on console but store it in two different ArrayLists.
Hence I tried to change the for loop to a normal for loop as follows:

```
ArrayList<List<String>> separatedTime = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
ArrayList<List<String>> separatedValues = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
String[] Array = new String[records.size()];
for(int i = 0; i < records.size(); i++) {
    Array[i] = (records[i]); //Error : Type of expression must be an array type. But it is resolved to List<String[]>
    String[] parts = Array[i].split(";");
    separatedTime.add(parts[0]); //Error : The method add(List<String>) in the type ArrayList<List<String>> is not applicable for the arguments (String) 
    separatedValues.add(parts[1]);
}
```

But this doesnot work. I cannot figure out why is it not working 
1) if it is changed from enhanced for loop to normal for loop. If I am wrong, how can I change to normal for loop?
2) After splitting with delimiter in normal for loop, why am I not able to store in Array List

I know I somewhere, somehow stepped into wrong. But unable to find out how can I rectify

Comment: try records.get(i);. records is a List, not an array

Comment: An ArrayList is not an array. The syntax to get the element at index i is different: `records.get(i)`.

Comment: I tried. It works only till splitting. But it cannot add in list. Only first element gets added. But after that, it throws an error. The loop doesnot take the next elements.

Comment: @Priya : Why do you need a List of List?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!! I solved using the following :

```
String[] Array = null;
            for(int i=0; i<records.size();i++)
            {
                Array = (records.get(i));
                String[] parts = Array[0].split(";");
                separatedTime.add(parts[0]);
                separatedValues.add(parts[1]);
            }
```

Everything is solved.. Thank you all for your time

Comment: You should stick to the Java Naming Conventions: variable names should start with lowercase.